# Extract rows if there is/are 'n' word/s before or after a pattern in postgres 11

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select, where-clause

I have following table in postgres

```
col1        col2            col3
NCT00000412 Drug            Placebo Calcitriol
NCT00000412 Drug            Placebo Alendronate
NCT00000774 Biological      Placebo version of rgp120/HIV-1MN
NCT00000774 Biological      Placebo version of rgp120/HIV-1SF2
NCT00005648 Drug            Gemcitabine with Placebo
NCT00007631 Drug            Tretinoin 0.1% cream or placebo
NCT00007735 Drug            Doxycycline (200mg/day) or Placebo
NCT00032435 Drug            PAL-40 Placebo
NCT00032435 Drug            abciximab placebo; reteplase placebo, abciximab  
NCT00032435 Drug            Valsartan placebo + nateglinide placebo
```

I am trying to extract those rows where placebo word has a single word before or after it. The expected output is:

```
col1        col2    col3
NCT00000412 Drug    Placebo Calcitriol
NCT00000412 Drug    Placebo Alendronate
NCT00032435 Drug    PAL-40 Placebo
```

I have tried following regex:

```
select * from table
where name ~* '\splacebo\w+' or name ~* '\w+placebo\s'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
select * from table
    where name ~* '^(?:placebo\s+\S+|\S+\s+placebo)$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vo3AuP/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:placebo\s+\S+|\S+\s+placebo)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `placebo\s+\S+` - `placebo`, then 1+ whitespaces and then 1+ non-whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `\S+\s+placebo` - 1+ non-whitespaces, then 1+ whitespaces and then `placebo`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where col3 ~* '(^\S+\s+placebo)|(placebo\s+\S+$)'
```

Breakdown:

```
(
    ^              beginning of the string
    \S+            1 to N characters other than a space
    \s+            1 to N spaces
    placebo        literal string "placebo"
)
|              OR
(
    placebo         literal string "placebo"
    \s+             1 to N spaces
    \S+             1 to N characters other than a space
    $               end of the string
)
```

I used `\S` instead of `\w` because you want to match on dashes (which `\w` doesn't do).

Comment: There is an edit in the input table. The query works perfectly fine but in some rows there are special characters which I would like to escape too.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can do this just using `like`:

```
where (name like '% Placebo%' and name not like '% % Placebo%') or
      (name like '%Placebo %' and name not like '%Placebo % %')
```